# Package dependency problems after upgrading 14.04 -> 15.04 with do-release-upgrade

Tags: 14.04, apt, 15.04, dpkg, dependencies

I tried to upgrade from x64 Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 with "do-release-upgrade". This left me with 8 broken packages, including grub, initscripts, upstart. The same error messages goes for all of them:
    `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of upstart (--configure):`  and similar for the other packages. I've tried running `apt-get install -f` and `dpkg --configure -a` to fix it but no luck. Essentially this means I can't upgrade any packages, and there are some other strange behaviour from the OS.

This is the error message I get when running `sudo apt-get update`. Some of it are in norwegian, but it basicly says "dependency problems" :

```
dpkg: error processing package grub-common (--configure):
 underprosessen installerte post-installation-skript returnerte feilstatus 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc-bin:
 grub-pc-bin krever grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-15ubuntu0.1). Men:
  Pakke grub-common er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package grub-pc-bin (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
Setter opp initscripts (2.88dsf-41ubuntu18) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S85vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'cron' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `cron'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `cron'
insserv: There is a loop between service ondemand and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service ondemand if started
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service spamassassin at depth 1
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service vpnagentd_init if started
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package initscripts (--configure):
 underprosessen installerte post-installation-skript returnerte feilstatus 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc:
 grub-pc krever grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-15ubuntu0.1). Men:
  Pakke grub-common er ikke satt opp enda.
 grub-pc krever grub-pc-bin (= 2.02~beta2-15ubuntu0.1). Men:
  Pakke grub-pc-bin er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub2-common:
 grub2-common krever grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-15ubuntu0.1). Men:
  Pakke grub-common er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package grub2-common (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of upstart-bin:
 upstart-bin krever initscripts. Men:
  Pakke initscripts er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package upstart-bin (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of upstart:
 upstart krever upstart-bin (= 1.13.2-0ubuntu2). Men:
  Pakke upstart-bin er ikke satt opp enda.
 upstart krever initscripts. Men:
  Pakke initscripts er ikke satt opp enda.

dpkg: error processing package upstart (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of friendly-recovery:
 friendly-recovery krever upstart | systemd-sysv. Men:
  Pakke upstart er ikke satt opp enda.
Pakken systemd-sysv er ikke installert.

dpkg: error processing package friendly-recovery (--configure):
 kravproblem - setter ikke opp pakken
Det oppsto feil ved behandling av:
 grub-common
 grub-pc-bin
 initscripts
 grub-pc
 grub2-common
 upstart-bin
 upstart
 friendly-recovery
```

Comment: I am sorry you are having problems. In my experience, fixing failed upgrades is sometimes difficult and sometimes impossible. It takes less time and is more reliable to do a fresh install.

Comment: Start the commands `LANG=C; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade ` and replace your error message in your question.

Comment: Update: I took your advice @bodhi.zazen and did a fresh install. 2/2 times I've tried to upgrade distro directly has failed, I think I'll stick to traditional means up upgrading from now on. Thanks for answers, guys!