# New software can't be installed, because there is a problem with the software currently installed. Problem with rhythmbox & udev

Tags: software-center, dpkg, rhythmbox

I am currently running the Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf (development branch) and am having problems installing and uninstalling software. would you be able to help me with this?

When I open the software center I get the following message:

```
"New software can't be installed, because there is a problem with the software currently installed. Do you want to repair this problem now?"
```

I press repair and I get the following error message:

```
Package operation failed

Details:

dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugins:
 rhythmbox-plugins depends on librhythmbox-core9 (= 3.2.1-1ubuntu3.1); however:
  Version of librhythmbox-core9 on system is 3.2.1-1ubuntu3.
 rhythmbox-plugins depends on rhythmbox (= 3.2.1-1ubuntu3.1); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.
 rhythmbox-plugins depends on gir1.2-rb-3.0 (= 3.2.1-1ubuntu3.1); however:
  Version of gir1.2-rb-3.0 on system is 3.2.1-1ubuntu3.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox-plugins (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune:
 rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune depends on rhythmbox (= 3.2.1-1ubuntu3.1); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.
```

It seems like there is a problem with the package udev. Would you be able to help me with this? Thank you in advance!

---

I have run "sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 udev" as suggested. Please see the output below.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 udev
ensure_diversions: new, (re)loading
 process queue pkg udev:amd64 queue.len 0 progress 1, try 1  
D000040: checking dependencies of udev:amd64 (- <none>)  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libacl1  
       checking non-provided pkg libacl1:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libblkid1  
       checking non-provided pkg libblkid1:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libc6  
       checking non-provided pkg libc6:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libkmod2  
       checking non-provided pkg libkmod2:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libselinux1  
       checking non-provided pkg libselinux1:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> lsb-base  
       checking non-provided pkg lsb-base:all  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> adduser  
       checking non-provided pkg adduser:all  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libudev1  
       checking non-provided pkg libudev1:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> util-linux  
       checking non-provided pkg util-linux:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> procps  
       checking non-provided pkg procps:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> debconf  
       checking non-provided pkg debconf:all  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> dpkg  
       checking non-provided pkg dpkg:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
D000040: ok 2 msgs >><<  
D000040:     checking Breaks  
       checking breaker bluez:amd64 virtbroken <none>  
       checking breaker brltty:amd64 virtbroken <none>  
       checking breaker printer-driver-foo2zjs:amd64 virtbroken <none>  
       checking breaker printer-driver-foo2zjs-common:all virtbroken <none>  
Setting up udev (225-1ubuntu9) ...  
D000002: fork/exec /var/lib/dpkg/info/udev.postinst ( configure 225-1ubuntu4 )  
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.  
insserv: warning: script 'S85vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides  
insserv: warning: script 'vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides  
insserv: There is a loop at service ondemand if started  
insserv: There is a loop between service ondemand and procps if started  
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2  
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!  
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached  
insserv:  loop involving service cups-browsed at depth 2  
insserv: There is a loop at service vpnagentd_init if started  
insserv: There is a loop between service vpnagentd_init and hwclock if started  
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1  
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4  
insserv: There is a loop between service ondemand and urandom if started  
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4  
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2  
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 4  
insserv:  loop involving service vpnagentd_init at depth 1  
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!  
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header  
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):  
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1  
 ensure_diversions: same, skipping  
D000040: checking dependencies of systemd:amd64 (- <none>)  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libacl1  
       checking non-provided pkg libacl1:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libapparmor1  
       checking non-provided pkg libapparmor1:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libaudit1  
       checking non-provided pkg libaudit1:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libblkid1  
       checking non-provided pkg libblkid1:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libcap2  
       checking non-provided pkg libcap2:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libcryptsetup4  
       checking non-provided pkg libcryptsetup4:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libkmod2  
       checking non-provided pkg libkmod2:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libmount1  
       checking non-provided pkg libmount1:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libpam0g  
       checking non-provided pkg libpam0g:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig - 
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libseccomp2  
       checking non-provided pkg libseccomp2:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libselinux1  
       checking non-provided pkg libselinux1:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libsystemd0  
       checking non-provided pkg libsystemd0:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> util-linux  
       checking non-provided pkg util-linux:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> mount  
       checking non-provided pkg mount:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> sysv-rc  
       checking non-provided pkg sysv-rc:all  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> udev  
       checking non-provided pkg udev:amd64  
       not configured/able  
         returning 0  
     found 0  
   found 0 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> adduser  
       checking non-provided pkg adduser:all  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libcap2-bin  
       checking non-provided pkg libcap2-bin:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libc6  
       checking non-provided pkg libc6:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libgcrypt20  
       checking non-provided pkg libgcrypt20:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> liblzma5  
       checking non-provided pkg liblzma5:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
   checking group ...  
     checking possibility  -> libselinux1  
       checking non-provided pkg libselinux1:amd64  
       is installed, ok and found  
     found 3  
   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -  
D000040: ok 0 msgs >> systemd depends on udev; however:  
  Package udev is not configured yet.  
<<  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 udev
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/448961/subprocess-installed-post-installation-script-returned-error-exit-status-247#449022), substitute gconf2 for udev in the commands.

Comment: I have added the output from "sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 udev" in the question above. I apologize but would you be able to further help me?

Comment: `warning: script 'vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides` - you appear to have Cisco AnyConnect VPN installed. Could you try either uninstalling it or [these instructions to add LSB headers to /etc/init.d/vpnagentd_init](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=53192#p322587)

Comment: There's actually a [dupe question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/672703/package-dependency-problems-after-upgrading-14-04-15-04-with-do-release-upgra) of this same problem but no answer so do report if it works or not.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! I used the following to uninstall the software:  "sudo /opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpn_uninstall.sh". Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. Can you [accept the answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer#1141) below so we can mark the other question as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is:

```
warning: script 'vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

Cisco AnyConnect VPN software is installed and the init script is missing LSB headers. Either uninstall the software (`sudo /opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpn_uninstall.sh`) or add the following LSB headers to `/etc/init.d/vpnagentd_init`:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: vpnagentd_init
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start Cisco vpn agent daemon at boot time
# Description: Cisco vpn agent daemon
### END INIT INFO
```